# How to access rails methods in a rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I followed [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html) tutorial to create a rails plugin.

[Section 3](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#extending-core-classes) explains how to add a method to string that is available anywhere in a Rails application. Now for my case, I want to be able to access rails methods in the plugin itself.

For example in `lib/plugin/my_plugin/my_plugin.rb` I want to use:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

But every time running the gem with an executable it throws following error:

```
undefined method `eager_load!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Now I know this error is thrown because there's no Rails application, but I added the plugin to a Rails application and it also doesn't seem to work (same error) and can't find another way to get this working. Am I approaching this problem the wrong way or is there even a better way?

`lib/plugin/my_plugin/my_plugin.rb`:

```
require 'rails'

class MyPlugin
  def fetch_models

    arr_models = []

    Rails.application.eager_load!

    ::ApplicationRecord.descendants.each do |model|
      arr_models[] << model
    end
  end
end
```

**Steps reproduce:**

1. Create a new plugin `rails plugin new custom`
2. Add `lib/custom/generator.rb`

`lib/custom/generator.rb`:

```
require 'faker'
require 'rails'

class Generator
  def fetch_models

    arr_models = []

    Rails.application.eager_load!

    ApplicationRecord.descendants.each do |model|
      arr_models[] << model
    end
  end
end
```

3. Edit `lib/custom.rb`

`lib/custom.rb`:

```
require "custom/generator"
require "custom/version"
require "custom/railtie"

module Custom
  def self.generate
    generator = Generator.new
    models = generator.fetch_models
  end
end
```

4. Add executable in `bin/`

`bin/custom`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'custom'
Custom.generate
```

5. Edit `custom.gemspec` so that `bin/test` passes
6. Execute following commands:

```
$ bundle exec rake build
$ bundle exec rake install
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, can you provide a complete example?

Comment: @aristotll added example in the question. Hope it'll work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins usually are built to extend core classes.
Using the generator and following the linked guide at `my_plugin/lib/my_plugin/rails_core_ext.rb` you have to use class you want to extend.

Your code become

```
class RailsPlayground::Application
  def fetch_models
    arr_models = []
    Rails.application.eager_load!
    ApplicationRecord.descendants.each do |model|
      arr_models[] << model
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
class RailsPlayground::Application
  def fetch_models
    Rails.application.eager_load!
    ApplicationRecord.descendants
  end
end
```

Comment: `RailsPlayground` is the namespace of your app